# How to select closest gps coordinate from database?

Tags: php, mysql, gps, coordinates

I have table `GPS_tbl` in mysql database `my_db`. In `GPS_tbl` there are four columns `1)uid` `2)latitude` `3)longitude` `4)regid`. In columns `2)latitude` `3)longitude` different values of `latitude` and `longitude` are already stored as float, now what i want is when user send his/her `gps coordinates in terms of latitude and longitude` through `POST()` compare these user sent coordinate with already stored coordinates in columns `2)latitude` `3)longitude` and the coordinate in columns `2)latitude` `3)longitude` which is closest to user sent coordinate select the `regid` against it. Please someone help me how to do this in `php`.

This is how user is sending his/her GPS coordinates.

```
    $lati = $_POST['lati'];
    $longi = $_POST['longi'];
    $float_value_of_lati = floatval($lati);
    $float_value_of_longi = floatval($longi);
```

This is `GPS_tbl`

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|     uid      | latitude   | longitude   |   regid     |
+--------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|      1       |  73.3433   |  18.5223    |APA91W-ClDoS |
|              |            |             |             |
+--- ----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|      2       |  43.3433   |  24.5523    |BON91W-ClDoS |
|              |            |             |             |
+--- ----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|      3       |  55.3433   |  37.5323    |WCD71P-ClDoS |
|              |            |             |             |
+--- ----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to explain to you how to connect to the MySQL server, get an instance of the database, and run an SQL query. There are plenty of tutorials for that. I'm going to help you with the query. For this purpose we will use the **Pythagorean theorem**. It's not the best approach because Earth in not flat, but I think it will work (not in middle of the Pacific where we pass from -180º to 180º, though)

```
    "SELECT uid,regid, sqrt(latitude-".$users_latitude.")+sqrt(longitude-".user_longitude.") AS SQRT_DIST 
FROM GPS_tbl ORDER BY SQRT_DIST LIMIT 1;
```

This is how you will get the closest point.

Note that the returned distance is distance^2.

Comment: I am trying to apply but it's giving me error can u please correct mistakes in this query.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT regid sqrt(lati-$lati)+sqrt(longi-$longi) AS SQRT_DIST FROM gps ORDER BY SQRT_DIST limit 1");

Comment: hi. i think the query is ok and you only have to change the name of the variables so they match the ones you have. "sqrt(lati-$lati)" : ¿isnt your column named latidute? Be carrefull with the names you asing to things. A log of the error will be usefull too.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php  please check the tutorials like this  to calculate distance between user sent coordinates and stored ones .After calculating distances sort the result set to get the nearest one.